# How to change datagridview column width after binding datasource?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview, datasource

How can one change `datagridview` column `width`? I have tried the following way but it does not work. Why is it unchanged?

```
  string[] strArrDoctor = new string[] {"ID", "Name", "Specialization", "Contact No", "Experience(Years)", "Delete" };
           //strin of array which contains Patient table columns names
            string[] strArrPatient = new string[] {"ID", "Name", "Join Date", "Ailment", "Doctor ID", "Delete" };
            if (rBtnDoctor.Checked)
            {
                for (int intIndex = 0; intIndex < dgvShowRecords.Columns.Count; intIndex++)
                {
                    //assigning Column names with our specified String of arrays
                    dgvShowRecords.Columns[intIndex].HeaderText = strArrDoctor[intIndex];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int intIndex = 0; intIndex < dgvShowRecords.Columns.Count;      intIndex++)
                {
                    dgvShowRecords.Columns[intIndex].HeaderText=strArrPatient[intIndex];
                }
            }
            //dgvShowRecords is Datagridview Name
            dgvShowRecords.Columns["Name"].Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.True;
            dgvShowRecords.Columns["Name"].Width = 200;
            dgvShowRecords.Columns["ID"].Width = 20;
```

please anyone know reason why it is unchanged let me know.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
dgvShowRecords.AutoResizeColumns();
```